# In "Le Chevalier aux épines", what are the 3 deaths of this character?

Tags: books, the-knight-of-thorns

In the end of the third and last tome of "Le Chevalier aux épines" by Jean-Philippe Jaworski (currently only available in French),

> the eponymous knight Vaumacel loses his life three times in his attempt to "handle" the situation of duchess Audéarde.

What are the 3 causes ?

I'm OK with 2 of my 3 guesses, but not the 3rd :

> - one life lost to Amlyn in the duchess' room
>  - one (the last one) lost for bleeding out and not tending to his wounds in time
>  - Between them: is it the "deal" (involuntary "evocation") he made with the "ghosts" while fleeing for them to stop bothering his group? Why would it do that?

Comment: Adding a tag, in English because that's the default language of the site.